# regex how to get one or more of "(.*)#" without grouping them?

Tags: regex, regex-group

im a real Regex beginner. I have the folloing string:
`<string1#string2#string3#string4>"` from that I want to get
`Match 0: <string1#string2#string3#string4> Groups:  "string1","string2","string3","string4"`

I want to all the strings to captured in different groups of one match. I've already tried: `<(.*)#(.*)#(.*)#(.*)>`. How can I look for one or more of these combination `(.*)#` without making another group so it works with any amount of strings?

Comment: Repeated capturing groups usually keep the last captured value. Without knowing your regex flavor/library, it is not possible to give you a good answer. You may capture all inside `<...>` with `<([^<>]+)>` and then split the Group 1 value with `#`.

Comment: For any amount of string I would suggest this syntax: \w.*?[0-9]